# How to convert long long ASCII hex values into a string?

Tags: c++, c, string, hex

I have a `long long` holding ASCII hex values and want to convert it to a string. I have this code:

```
char myBuffer[8];
long long myLongLong = 0x7177657274797569;
sprintf(myBuffer,"%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c",myLongLong);
int x;
cout << myBuffer;
cin >> x;
return 0;
```

The hex code should be `"qwertyui"`, but it always gives other value.

I tried with `%c`, `%s`, `%X` but it doesn't give me the output I need, the closest was `%c` but it prints out only one char.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code is wrong in so many ways I don't know where to start...

- `myBuffer` is too small to hold the 8 `chars` + the NUL terminator, ie. should be `myBuffer[9]`.
- `sprintf` is expecting 8 arguments, you're only passing 1. The other required arguments will be whatever's on the stack.
- `myLongLong` is not a `char`
- You don't take into account endianness.
- You're using C functions and doing things in a C way in C++. Why don't you use `std::string`s as opposed to C-style strings and `stringstream`s as an alternative to `sprintf`?

The closest *almost* working example of what you want, *as similar to your example*, is something like:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
   char myBuffer[9];
   long long myLongLong = 0x7177657274797569;
   char *c_ptr = (char*)&myLongLong;
   sprintf(myBuffer,"%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c", c_ptr[0], c_ptr[1], c_ptr[2], c_ptr[3], c_ptr[4], c_ptr[5], c_ptr[6], c_ptr[7]);
   int x;
   cout<<myBuffer;
   cin>>x;
   return 0;
}
```

Which will output `"iuytrewq"` on my little-endian machine. As I mentioned, that doesn't take into account the endianness. If the machine is little-endian then you could read/print the bytes in reverse.

I really don't understand why you're trying to do this though...

Comment: Thanks, your code works but reversed :), how to reverse it?
I'm trying to decypher a DES encryption and I'm trying to optimize my code to the maximum.

Comment: @SherifMaherEaid: In that example, just reverse the arguments to `sprintf`: `..., c_ptr[7], c_ptr[6], c_ptr[5], ..., c_ptr[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
union { char buf[8]; long long num; } u;
u.num =  0x7177657274797569LL;
cout << u.str << endl;
```

But I don't understand what you want really to do. What about endianness ?

Comment: little endian.
I am trying to decypher a DES encryption.

Comment: your code works. but it's u.buf not u.str , also the u.buf has some extra garbage characters when displaying it, but when debugging, I can see it contains all the characters right, the problem is just in displaying.

Answer (score 1):

Use a string stream

```
long long myLongLong = 0x7177657274797569;
std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::hex << myLongLong;
std::cout << ss << std::endl
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to print each byte of the long-long as an ascii char?

Then you need to loop over the long long extracting one byte at a time, look at bit shifts and masking.

Hint it's generally easier (if you know the length) to work from the last byte and shift right

or - you could just memcpy the long-long into the char array - except for any byte ordering issues

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{

char myBuffer[8];
long long myLongLong = 0x7177657274797569;

for(int i = 0; i<8;i++)
{
    myBuffer[i] = myLongLong>>(64-(i+1)*8);
}

cout<<myBuffer<<endl;

return 0;

}
```